# Iterate over a MySql subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

I have the following subquery...

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'table' AND table_name = 'some_table_name' 
 AND column_name LIKE 'list_type_%'
```

...which I use to select all column names that start with list_type. The value can be either white or black (whitelist, blacklist), but should default to black in certain cases (but not in all cases - as I want the default to be empty - so setting a DEFAULT value to black is not an option).

In such a "certain case" I would like to iterate over the results of the subquery, as if I did (pseudo code)

```
foreach (result as column_name) {
 if (column_name == x) {
  values .= ", white"
 }
 else {
  values .= ", black"
 }
}
```

I would then use a concatenated string of column names and their values to insert a row. Is there any way to do such a thing in SQL(Mysql)?

Alternatively, I could simply call the PHP PDO query method twice and do some string converting in between, but I suppose that would be slower.

Comment: This sounds like a truly terrible idea.  What is the wider problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to be able to dynamically add new column names, (starting with "list_type_"), without having to modify PHP code everywhere, which is why I select the column names from the information_schema

Comment: You need to store all these list types in a **separate table**, where one column would be list type and one with value

Comment: @eggyal As the application expands, more list_type column names may be added. I would like to have them automatically default to black in "certain cases", without having to hardcode all the column names that start with "list_type_" for every time PHP adds a row

Comment: @user2180613: you need to read up on normalization. You don't add more list types as columns, you add them as rows in a table. I'll explain in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not to dynamically add columns, it's to change your database structure. This is a process called normalization, and you should learn it now before you construct something completely unmaintainable.

Here's a starter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

In your case, you want to have some arbitrary number of list type columns in some table. What you really want to have is a table that has more or less the following columns

- item_key
- list_type_key

You'll want another table that has one row for each type of list. This table can grow over time. It's easier to add rows than columns. That's what rows are for. Whenever you add a new list type, you add a new entry in this list type table. Then, in your other table, you can start associating entities with list types.

If you can give me more information about your overall schema, I can be more specific in my directions.